# Dynamic casting pointer to Reference and reference to pointer

Tags: c++, dynamic, casting

I am new to CPP and trying to learn dynamic casting . Unfortunately, am getting the below error

```
main.cpp: In function 'void PRINT(A&)':
main.cpp:30:40: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'Ref_A' (of type 'class A') to type 'class B*' (source is not a pointer) B *Ref_PTR = dynamic_cast<B*>(Ref_A);
```

If some one can teach me, what is going on ?

Can we cast reference to pointer or pointer to reference ?
Can we cast only Base reference to Derived reference ?
Can we cast only Base pointer to derived pointer ?

========================================================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual void dummy() {cout<< "Am in Base Class \n"; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void dummy() {cout<< "Am in first Derived Class \n"; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
  virtual void dummy() {cout<< "Am in second Derived Class \n"; }
};

void PRINT(A &);

int  main()
{
   B b;
   C c;
   PRINT(b);
   PRINT(c);
   return 0;
}

void PRINT(A &Ref_A )
{
    try
    {
        B &Ref = dynamic_cast<B&>(Ref_A);
        Ref.dummy();
    }
    catch(std::bad_cast exp) { std::cout<<"Caught bad cast in the Second catch \n"; }

    B *Ref_PTR = dynamic_cast<B*>(Ref_A);
    if (Ref_PTR)
     Ref_PTR->dummy();
    //Ref_A.dummy();
}
```

Comment: "Can we cast reference to pointer or pointer to reference ?" No, thats what the address-of and the indirection operators are for.

Comment: Ref_A is passed by reference, but that doesn't mean it is a pointer. The error actually says the same _"source is not a pointer"_

Comment: why not just do Ref_A.dummy() ? the function is virtual.

Comment: Anyway, I edited your code to something slightly easier to read. Roll back if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: I thought we can do the below casting Derived *p = dynamic_cast<Derived*> ( Base& ). is this correct or wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we cast reference to pointer or pointer to reference ?

Nope. A reference and a pointer are different beasts in the C++ type ecosystem.

> Can we cast only Base reference to Derived reference ? 
>   Can we cast only Base pointer to derived pointer ?

Generally yes. We cast references to references or pointers to pointers. But that's not to say we can't obtain a pointer from a reference. That's what the address-of operator is for:

```
B *Ref_PTR = dynamic_cast<B*>( &Ref_A );
```

Comment: Is that a syntax (&Ref_A) in this code B *Ref_PTR = dynamic_cast<B*>( &Ref_A ); to obtain a pointer from a reference ?

Comment: @PrasathShanmugakani yes. Taking the address of a reference returns a pointer to the object being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

From [expr.dynamic.cast#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.dynamic.cast#1)

> The result of the expression `dynamic_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of
>   converting the expression v to type T. T shall be a pointer or
>   reference to a **complete class type**, or “**pointer** to cv void”

In your code `void PRINT(A &Ref_A )`,

```
B &Ref = dynamic_cast<B&>(Ref_A);
```

`Ref_A` is a reference and you want to cast it to a reference `B&`.
This will result to `bad_­cast` as per [expr.dynamic.cast#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.dynamic.cast#9)

Do this instead:

```
B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&Ref_A); // cast to B*
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this.

```
B *Ref_PTR = dynamic_cast<B*>(&Ref_A);
```

but this is very ill, your class define `dummy()` as virtual so you should not cast from base class to derived class without very good justification.

you could use just `Ref_A.dummy();` and it will call the correct implementation